# Can't enable drupal 7 membership suite module

Tags: 7, deployment

Just installed MS core, Membership suite on drupal 7. installation is ok, I can see the new module on the admin page, but can not click on the enable box to activate/enable the new module. it says "Entity is missing" in red.
any input would be appericiated.

thanks

Comment: entity module is needed, install it and proceed

Comment: Kindly provide screenshot for better reference.